# Change plot size in pandas-profiling/ydata-profiling

Tags: python, jupyter, pandas-profiling

How can I change pandas-profiling's plot size and font size (correlations: heatmap, missing values plots and heatmap) in Jupiter Notebook?

```
import pandas as pd
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport

profile_test = ProfileReport(test, title="Profiling Report", interactions=None)
profile_test.to_widgets()
```

The correlation plot has a lot of information in it and is currently too small

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]